# I seem to dance, I am not a dancer. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> I seem to dance, I am not a dancer
>
> I may pop, I am not a bubble
>
> I may even roar, I am not a lion
>
> I am high on fever, I am not a patient
>
> I can force you to shut your eyes, I am not sleep
>
> I can give you life, I am not your Creator
>
> I can take it too, I am not your Destroyer
>
> I am made of three, but alone none would work

Who am I? And who make me?

Comment: Probably Air my guess. It suits all the option ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My first thought was that you are

> **Fire**

*I seem to dance, I am not a dancer*

> Flames seem to dance

*I may pop, I am not a bubble*

> Fire crackles and pops

*I may even roar, I am not a lion*

> Roaring bonfires

*I am high on fever, I am not a patient*

> Definitely high temperature

*I can force you to shut your eyes, I am not sleep*

> You often have to close your eyes approaching a large fire - or smoke might make you close your eyes near even a smaller fire

*I can give you life, I am not your Creator*

> Some tree seeds actually need fire to germinate (and eg forest fires are often needed to clear room for new growth). Humans maybe don’t strictly need fire to live, at least in some climates, but it certainly makes life in more northern latitudes possible.

*I can take it too, I am not your Destroyer*

> People perish in fire with unfortunate regularity.

*I am made of three, but alone none would work*

> Provided by [@Rimply](/users/57972/rimply) in a now-deleted comment: fire requires heat, fuel, and an oxidizing agent. Take away any one of the three and there is no fire. Certainly no single one of the three alone would suffice either. (See [Fire Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_triangle) for more info.)

Comment: I was close then :-P

Answer (score 3):

You are probably

> water

*I seem to dance, I am not a dancer*

> Dancing water in a river.

*I may pop, I am not a bubble*

> Again the noise of a river??

*I may even roar, I am not a lion*

> Roaring waterfalls.

*I am high on fever, I am not a patient*

> High waves?

*I can force you to shut your eyes, I am not sleep*

> Spraying water at someone would make them close their eyes.

*I can give you life, I am not your Creator*

> Water is needed for life.

*I can take it too, I am not your Destroyer*

> Drowning.

*I am made of three, but alone none won't work*

> Water is H2O - made of 2 hydrogen and 1 oxygen, which alone would be useless.

Comment: That's a good (and too fast) answer, but could you explain why do high waves have fever? Btw I was thinking of another answer.

Comment: @Natasha I was hoping that "fever" was a metaphor and the important word was "high".

Comment: Well no... Fever is quite an important word here.

Answer (score 2):

I'll go for:

> Blood

I seem to dance, I am not a dancer

> Blood moves with a regular rhythm so, metaphorically, it dances.

I may pop, I am not a bubble

> Blood may come out if you pop a pimple, or similar.

I may even roar, I am not a lion

> Blood can make a roaring noise in your ears.

I am high on fever, I am not a patient

> Fever will raise your blood temperature.

I can force you to shut your eyes, I am not sleep

> Many people don't like the sight of blood.

I can give you life, I am not your Creator

> Blood is symbolically associated with life.

I can take it too, I am not your Destroyer

> Excessive bleeding can kill you.

I am made of three, but alone none won't work

> There are three important kinds of blood cell, and you need all of them.

Answer (score 0):

With some word play, we could also wrangle you into being

> **A joint**

*I seem to dance, I am not a dancer*

> "This joint is jumpin'," as Fats Waller put it

*I may pop, I am not a bubble*

> Anatomical joints pop

*I may even roar, I am not a lion*

> A bar roars over the outcome of a sporting event

*I am high on fever, I am not a patient*

> A burning joint can make you high

*I can force you to shut your eyes, I am not sleep*

> Eye toke: smoke from your joint gets in your eyes

*I can give you life, I am not your Creator*

> A joint in the vulgar sense is key to procreation

*I can take it too, I am not your Destroyer*

> A joint as in jail can take the best years of your life

*I am made of three, but alone none would work*

> The three bones in the knee joint—femur, tibia, patella—are useless individually